# How to update elastic search Indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have added data to my elastic search indices using logstash from a csv file.
I have made some changes to my csv and now want it to be reflected on elastic indices.

How do I go about doing it?

Logstash Cofig I used to uplaod data to index.

```
    input{
        file{
        path => "/Users/apple/Desktop/data/gkdata.csv"
        start_position =>"beginning"

        }
    }
    filter{
        csv{
        separator => ","
        columns => ["Index", "Category",    "Sub category", "Sub Sub Category", "Products", "Measure", "Price", "Description",  "Gst"]
        }
        mutate{convert => ["Index", "float"] }
        mutate{convert => ["Price", "float"] }
        mutate{convert => ["Gst", "float"] }
    }
    output{
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => "host"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "xyz"
            index => "gkdb"
            }

    }
```

I use this command to upload data to my index

```
bin/logstash -f /Users/apple/Desktop/data/logstash_db.config
```

Comment: Can you show your logstash configuration?

Comment: @Val I added the config file in question

Comment: Ok, since you don't have any ID field, if you launch Logstash again, you'll end up with duplicate documents. The best you can do is simply delete your `gkdb` index and run Logstash again using the updated CSV file

Comment: @Val. I indexed my updated CSV file and this time I also added an index filed with a unique Id for each row. For future- when I make changes to my CSV file, How do I go about updating my index?

Comment: Good, in the future, you can just relaunch logstash and all will be well

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing the same, just wanted to confirm